# OpenVPN: Options error: "Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in client.ovpn:130: tls-remote (2.4.6)"

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tls

I am getting this error message (title) in the OpenVPN log file and I cannot connect to my university's VPN. The message points to an error with line 130 of the **client.ovpn** file. However, I don't know what exactly is wrong with it and how I should fix it. Most of my classmates are able to connect. The config files are provided by the university.

Line 130: **tls-remote roadwarrior.inf.hs-anhalt.de**

It has been advised that the connection may fail if the Windows firewalls are enabled. I disabled them, but I keep getting the same error message.

I would appreciate any help related to this error. Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That particular option was deprecated and removed in OpenVPN 2.4

The new syntax is:

```
verify-x509-name roadwarrior.inf.hs-anhalt.de name
```

To solve your problem, you can try

- Meddling with the client.ovpn file and make the edit I suggested
- Telling your university IT they should support newer/current versions of OpenVPN
- Rolling back your client version to before OpenVPN 2.4

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It solved my problem right away.